# GNU make: How can I use automatic variables for multiple targets in my prerequisites?

Tags: makefile, target, prerequisites

I am using GNU make for compiling my fortran projects. In my special case, I have two static libraries each with a list of related objects. My Makefile contains:

```
LIB_BTMOD = btmod
LIB_btmod_OBJS = \
  m_bt_check \
  m_bt_execute

LIB_MDLMOD = mdlmod
LIB_mdlmod_OBJS = \
  m_model_set \
  m_model_run
```

After that I want to create each library with

```
$(LIB_BTMOD) : $(LIB_btmod_OBJS:%=%.o)
  ar rc lib$(@).a $^

$(LIB_MDLMOD) : $(LIB_mdlmod_OBJS:%=%.o)
  ar rc lib$(@).a $^
```

That solution seems a bit redundant for me. How can I use it with only one multiple target?

My proposition looks like:

```
$(LIB_BTMOD) $(LIB_MDLMOD) : $(LIB_$(@)_OBJS:%=%.o)
  ar rc lib$(@).a $^
```

but that does not extend the prerequisites as intended. What did I wrong at this point?

Thank you very much for your help.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The way to do what you intend is to first rearrange elements:

```
$(LIB_BTMOD) : $(LIB_btmod_OBJS:%=%.o)
$(LIB_MDLMOD) : $(LIB_mdlmod_OBJS:%=%.o)

$(LIB_BTMOD) $(LIB_MDLMOD) :
    ar rc lib$(@).a $^
```

Then rewrite the prerequisite lines:

```
$(LIB_BTMOD) : $(addsuffix .o,$(LIB_btmod_OBJS))
$(LIB_MDLMOD) : $(addsuffix .o,$(LIB_mdlmod_OBJS))
```

Then attempt to combine them (and fail):

```
$(LIB_BTMOD) $(LIB_MDLMOD) : $(addsuffix .o,$(LIB_$(@)_OBJS))
```

Then remember [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) and get the syntax right:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(LIB_BTMOD) $(LIB_MDLMOD) : $$(addsuffix .o,$$(LIB_$$(@)_OBJS))
    ar rc lib$(@).a $^
```

That said, I think you'd be better off appending the `.o` when you construct the object lists, rather than on the fly.

Comment: Secondary expansion was a good idea. You are right: I should add suffixes and prefixes better before using as prerequisites. Now it works for me. Thanks!